# How to read a remote JSON file with jQuery.getJSON()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new with Javascript and I would like to read a remote JSON file with `getJSON()`. For some reason my function returns a syntax error `Unexpected token )` but I can't figure out what is wrong.

This is what I do, am'I missing something ?

```
var url = "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json";

$.getJSON(url, function (json) {

    console.log(json);
    alert(json);

)};
```

[Link to the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aaqm4r2v/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a javascript error

```
var url = "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json";

$.getJSON(url, function (json) {

    console.log(json);
    alert(json);

}); // here swapped the bracets
```